# Notary attested true copy of passport

Tags: india, notaries

Where can one notarize a copy of a passport in India to confirm it is a true copy which is signed, sealed and verified by an appointed notary?

Answer (score 1):

The early answer does not reflect the position in India.

Section 8(1) of the [Notaries Act, 1952](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/2172?view_type=browse&sam_handle=123456789/1362) states:

> A notary may do all or any of the following acts by virtue of his office, namely:—
>
> - (a) verify, authenticate, certify or attest the execution of **any instrument**;

And section 2(b) defines this emboldened text:

> - (b) "instrument" includes every document by which any right or liability is, or purports to be, created, transferred, modified, limited, extended, suspended, extinguished or recorded;

You can find a 1282 page pfd by following the *List of notaries* link [**here**](https://legalaffairs.gov.in/notary-cell)

Comment: By what line of reasoning does a photocopy of a passport create, transfer, modify, limit, extend, suspend, extinguish, or record a right or liability?

Comment: To precis: *A notary may authenticate (an) instrument (being any) document by which any right is created.* Doesn't a passport create the right of protection?

Comment: @JBentley: The sentence structure seems to be "verify" or "authenticate" or "certify" or "attest the execution".  Since the question deals with the "authenticate" verb, execution has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, I had read the verbs as attaching to the word execute (as in "verify the execution, authenticate the execution") but I see it makes more sense that "attest the execution" is a separate item in the list. It is somewhat poorly worded.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot. You can only notarize a declaration, e.g. you say it it so, and the  notary attests to your saying so. You probably have to produce a real original passport for whatever purpose you had in mind.

Comment: This answer is apparently [incorrect for 28 US states and the District of Columbia](https://members.usnotaries.net/news.asp?AssetID=586).  As to India, I am not sure, but it looks like it depends on whether a passport copy is an "instrument" as defined in the [Notaries Act 1952 (pdf)](http://legalaffairs.gov.in/sites/default/files/The_Notaries_Act_1952_0.pdf) §2(b) or whether certifying copies has been otherwise "prescribed" as a notarial act under §8(1)(i).